# Finding Index of in combination with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to find the start position of the following in a string:

{UPPERCASESTRINGINANYLENGTH(

What is the fastest way of doing that? Thanks

Comment: what starting position? And where is your code? And why do you need a regex?

Comment: The index position in the full string that matches the format {UPPERCASESTRINGINANYLENGTH(. I do not know if there are any alternative ways of matching { + UPPERCASECHARACTERS + (. As far as I know string.IndexOf cannot do this type of wild card matching to find index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can;

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches("  {AAA(1)}  {XXX(2)} ", @"\{[A-Z]+\("))
{
   if (match.Success)
      int pos = match.Index;
```